# How to merge reports having specified range for last modified date with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, merge, last-modified

I have 2 macros that I would like to combine. Both work fine separately:

1. Macro to merge all csv files in the folder (found somewhere online):

```
Sub ImportCSV()

Dim strSourcePath As String
Dim strDestPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
strSourcePath = "\\lcwfsv1\users\e668714\Desktop\Workings\10. Merge Files\PathToMerge"

If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

'Change the path to the destination folder accordingly
strDestPath = "\\lcwfsv1\users\e668714\Desktop\Workings\10. Merge Files"

If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"

strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    If Cnt = 1 Then
       r = 1
   Else
       r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End If
    Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
        If Cnt > 1 Then
           Line Input #1, strData
       End If
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            x = Split(strData, ";")
            For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
    'Name strSourcePath & strFile As strDestPath & strFile
    strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Cnt = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

2. Macro to merge only csv files after specified date and time (last modified):

```
Sub Merge()

Call ExtractUserInfo
Call OpenCSVFiles

End Sub
```

```
Sub ExtractUserInfo()

Set mWB = ThisWorkbook

uPath = BackSlash(Main.Range("uPath").Text)
uDate = Main.Range("uDate").Value
uHour = Main.Range("uHour").Value

End Sub
```

```
Sub OpenCSVFiles()

Call OnStart

Dim arr, f
arr = AllFilesNewestFirst(uPath & "*.csv")

For Each f In arr
    If Len(f) > 0 Then

        If DateValue(FileDateTime(uPath & f)) < uDate Or (DateValue(FileDateTime(uPath & f)) = uDate And TimeValue(FileDateTime(uPath & f)) < uHour) Then Exit For

        Set uFile = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=uPath & f, UpdateLinks:=False, Local:=True)
        Call CopyData(uFile)
        uFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    End If
Next f

Call OnEnd
MsgBox "Reports have been merged!"

End Sub
```

```
Function AllFilesNewestFirst(pattern)
    Dim s As String
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim oExec As Object, cmd
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    cmd = "cmd /c dir """ & pattern & """ /A-D-H-S /b /o-d"
    s = oShell.Exec(cmd).StdOut.readall()
    AllFilesNewestFirst = Split(s, vbCrLf)
End Function
```

```
Sub CopyData(wb As Workbook)

Dim tRow As Double
Dim mRow As Double
tRow = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

If tRow > 1 Then

    mRow = mWB.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rcop = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing


    For Each rng In wb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(tRow, 32))
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                If Not rcop Is Nothing Then
                    Set rcop = Union(rng, rcop)
                Else
                    Set rcop = rng
                End If
            Else
                Set rcop = rng
            End If
    Next

    If Not rcop Is Nothing Then

        Intersect(rcop.EntireRow, wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:AF")).Copy

        mWB.Sheets(2).Range("a" & mRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        mWB.Sheets(2).Range("ag" & mRow + 1 & ":ag" & mWB.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count) = wb.Name

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

The reason why I want to do it is that first macro is many times faster even though it merges all files by default.

Here's what I have so far (only edited sub OpenCSVFiles, rest stay the same), I am now stuck:

```
Sub OpenCSVFiles()

Call OnStart

Dim arr, f
arr = AllFilesNewestFirst(uPath & "*.csv")
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim x As Variant
Dim strData As String


For Each f In arr
    
        If DateValue(FileDateTime(uPath & f)) < uDate Or (DateValue(FileDateTime(uPath & f)) = uDate And TimeValue(FileDateTime(uPath & f)) < uHour) Then Exit For
        
        If Len(f) > 0 Then

        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        If Cnt = 1 Then
            r = 1
        Else
            r = Cells(Merged.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
       
        Open uPath & f For Input As #1
        If Cnt > 1 Then
           Line Input #1, strData
        End If
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            x = Split(strData, ";")
            For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                Merged.Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
                Merged.Cells(r, c + 2).Value = f
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        Close #1            

    End If
Next f

Call OnEnd
MsgBox "Reports have been merged!"

End Sub
```

The problem is:

1. It starts merging in correct time spot (ex. 1 June 2021, 17:05), however it stops after few days for some reason.
2. It creates 8 blank rows in the sheet between first and next row, which I could not have spotted in the code why it happens.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think #1 is a grouping issue in your `If` after the `Or` add a parenthesis and then close it before the `Then`. The second issue is probably a bunch of `;` that are causing additional iterations of a loop, though it's hard to tell, your best bet would be stepping through and seeing what happens to `r`.

Comment: Adding attitional parenthesis didnt help. For r, it jumps from 1 to 9 when it opens second file. And it does not matter what file is second (I deleted prev second and it still happens). Worth mentioning: most of thses files are empty (only first row, not to be merged).

Comment: I would suggest creating a list of files that meet your date criteria, using VBA to shell to either the command prompt or powershell, then use that list to process your merging.  Another option would be to do the entire operation in Power Query.  When you select data from a folder, one of the columns will be the modified date, which you could filter on.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Does it mean that merging these 2 macros the way I want is not feasible?

Comment: I'm sure it is feasible.  I'm just suggesting different approaches that might be easier to maintain, and run faster than what it looks like you are doing now.